# cant install a thing!

Tags: installation, command-line, software-center, dpkg, pidgin

OK. So when I try to install a something in the terminal, I get:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then try using apt-get -f install, but then:

```
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching pidgin-facebookchat:amd64
```

When I try to download pidgin facebookchat (from the Software Center) I can't to that either, cause I get a popup saying:

> Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it now?

I click repair, but it keeps asking me about it. Therefore I can't either install something from the Software Center.

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get -f install`? Also, see [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'sudo apt-cache clean' in the terminal